# Android recorded voice morphing or manipulation to funny voices

Tags: android, audio, voice, morphing

What are the options to be able to morph recorded voices to funny tones in Android? iPhone possibly has options like http://dirac.dspdimension.com, do we have some similar library for android that will help create funny voices from recorded files? The requirement is to create something on the lines of 'talking tom'/'chipmunkify' (if that helps understand the context).

If there are no ready libraries, what are other ways to do this?

Comment: There is no library for that as far as I know. You have to code it on your own. StackOverflow won't give you ready code, only ideas how to do.

Comment: @Leandros +1. I know that there are some C libraries you can use via the NDK. It's obviously harder to do, but it is possible.

Comment: As of now, there are plenty of voice-morphing apps available on android, do you mean to say that possibly all of them have coded their own voice-morphing logic? 

The task is complicated, but fairly standard so I'm still quite open to idea of an available library. But yes, doing something more customized, might as well require coding from scratch. In any case, I'm looking for insights from all directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most voice-modulating applications on mobile currently seem to be using variations of pitch-modulation and some additional audio-effects (note that voice-morphing is much bigger problem to solve).

On Android "AudioTrack" helps you adjust the pitch settings (and many other audio characteristics too) to manipulate the input audio leading to the required funny/"chip-munkified" version.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use AudioTrack. It is available since API 3 and is quite widely used. It will help you modify the frequency, and hence the pitch, of the audio file you want to distort. A higher pitch will give you the chipmunk like sound you were looking for.

However, due to its old age, AudioTrack may be difficult to implement for you. Try Android's **soundpool** api. Its flexible, can play tens of sounds at a time, and lets you modify pitch/frequency very easily.

Here is how I tested it (it works):

```
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
boolean isSoundLoaded = false;
float frequencyPitch = 1.3f; // tweak this. it accepts any number between 0.5f and 2.0f
int soundID = soundPool.load(filePath+fileName, 1);
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            isSoundLoaded = true;
            if(isSoundLoaded)
    {
    soundPool.play(soundID, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, frequencyPitch);
    }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of FFMPEG for voice changing purpose.

Example:

```
/**
 * Function to execute FFMPEG Query
 */
    private fun exceuteFFMPEG(cmd: Array<String>) {
        FFmpeg.execute(cmd)
        val rc = FFmpeg.getLastReturnCode()
        val output = FFmpeg.getLastCommandOutput()

        if (rc == RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS) {
            Log.i("GetInfo", "Command execution completed successfully.")
            hideProgress()
            isEffectAddedOnce = true
            start()
        } else if (rc == RETURN_CODE_CANCEL) {
            Log.i("GetInfo", "Command execution cancelled by user.")
        } else {
            Log.i(
                "GetInfo",
                String.format(
                    "Command execution failed with rc=%d and output=%s.",
                    rc,
                    output
                )
            )
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function used to play the audio like a Radio
     */
    private fun playRadio(fileName1: String, fileName2: String) {
        showProgress()
        player?.stop()
        val cmd = arrayOf(
            "-y",
            "-i",
            fileName1,
            "-af",
            "atempo=1",
            fileName2
        )//Radio

        exceuteFFMPEG(cmd)

    }

    /**
     * Function used to play the audio like a Chipmunk
     */
    private fun playChipmunk(fileName1: String, fileName2: String) {
        showProgress()
        player?.stop()
        val cmd = arrayOf(
            "-y",
            "-i",
            fileName1,
            "-af",
            "asetrate=22100,atempo=1/2",
            fileName2
        )//Chipmunk
        exceuteFFMPEG(cmd)
    }

    /**
     * Function used to play the audio like a Robot
     */
    private fun playRobot(fileName1: String, fileName2: String) {
        showProgress()
        player?.stop()
        val cmd = arrayOf(
            "-y",
            "-i",
            fileName1,
            "-af",
            "asetrate=11100,atempo=4/3,atempo=1/2,atempo=3/4",
            fileName2
        )//Robot
        exceuteFFMPEG(cmd)
    }

    /**
     * Function used to play the audio like a Cave
     */
    private fun playCave(fileName1: String, fileName2: String) {
        showProgress()
        player?.stop()
        val cmd = arrayOf(
            "-y",
            "-i",
            fileName1,
            "-af",
            "aecho=0.8:0.9:1000:0.3",
            fileName2
        )//Cave

        exceuteFFMPEG(cmd)

    }
```

For more details, you can refer the sample at

https://github.com/sachinvarma/VoiceChanger

Please have a look on to the below site for more information regarding informations that will help us to handle other effects.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html

Hope, this may help someone in future.

Comment: That works, Thanks it saved my time, but could also help extra, how to add other effect, how to find which effect need to asetrate or which effect need atempo.

Comment: Hi @KeyurNimavat, Happy to hear that the answer helped you. I have updated the answer with the link which will help you to get the necessary informations.

Answer (score 0):

Try embedding pure data inside your app. Pure data is awesome and fun to learn. Give it a try and its easy to morph the voice.